# Android emulator - dummy emulator-5554 and AVD ... is already running

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I've been trying to run this down for two days now and I am absolutely stumped.
Running on Windows 10.
Project builds fine.
I hit run, select Nexus 5x API 28 virtual device, the emulator boots, and the Nexus 5X runs without the app.

Run 'app' again and now my deployment options are a dummy Emulator-5554[Offline] and the Nexus. Selecting the Nexus gets me the "AVD Nexus_5X_API_28 is already running. If this is not the case..." error.
Selecting the unwelcomed Emulator-5554 returns an "error launching app" from Android Studio.

So here's what I've tried:

- Deleting the Nexus 5x files -- all of them.
- Installing a Pixel 2 instead -- problem is the same.
- Cold booting Nexus 5x -- no effect.
- ADB kill-server.
- ADB start-server.
- Tracing 5554 to the `qemu-system-etc.exe` application and killing it.
- Deleting `local/android/sdk`, and reinstalling Android Studio without saved settings.
- Different phones and different APIs.
- Switching on Developer Mode on the Nexus 5x.

The next step is formatting the hard drive and scorching the earth around it.

Has anyone seen this before?

Edit:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill
```

removes the emulator-5554  and closes android emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by building multiple instances of the emulator I wanted. The first instance sort of "plugs" the emulator 5554 hole. Then it's business as usual.